# CSS percentage getting the wrong value/misaligned nested div

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am having two problems with the checkboxes shown above. The styles applied on the parent and child are essentially:

```
.parent {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 24px;
   height: 24px;
   outline: 1px solid black;
   margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.child {
   width: 80%;
   height: 80%;
   flex: none;
   background-color: red;
}
```

The first problem is: when I go read the child's width via `getBoundingClientRect().width`, it shows me 19.1875, while it should be 24 * 80% = 19.2.

Secondly, how do I make the child square dead center? I have no idea why but they are all slightly to the left and the top. Side note: the parent and child in this case are both `<div>` elements.

**EDIT:**

```js
const child = document.querySelector('.child')
console.log(child.getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.child {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  flex: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-container'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1> H1 ELEMENT </h1>

<div class='parent-container'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='child'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above snippet is my best effort at replicating the problem. Firstly, the logged value of the child div's width seems to be incorrect (19.1875 instead of 19.2), though it might not actually affect their appearance.

Secondly, as I have discovered, the child component is only misaligned when there's nearby element that affects their positions. As seen in the snippet, the child element in the row of checkboxes above the `<h1>` are perfectly centered. But the child `div` in the ones below it are slightly closer to the top than the bottom. While it might not look obvious, it becomes very apparent when they are scaled up, like the photo at the top.

This is observed in most browsers, though in Firefox this effect is actually reversed (closer to the bottom than top). Are there anything I can do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: This is issue with custom checkbox.
This will render differently with different browser.
So there might alignment mismatch.
What I will suggest is to use image, this will not have alignment issue

Comment: Slightly to the left because `margin-right: 0.5em;` on the parent

Comment: @dalelandry I don't think so, as deleting the margin didn't fix the issue and doesn't explain the vertical misalignment. Also the margin would be on the outside of the parent not inside

Comment: perhaps you could add a snippit that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @dalelandry I have updated the answer with a snippet attached.

Answer (score 0):

I lack the in-depth knowledge about how different browsers handle subpixel rounding and rendering. But in this case, the margins and other properties expressed in `em` or `%` can cause elements to render at inconsistent positions (as we may be dealing with fractions of pixels, while still being limited by the actual pixels of the screen).

I am not aware of a general solution to this problem, but you could simply ensure that the difference of width and height between the parent and the child is divisible by 2. This difference can then be evenly distributed between left/right and top/bottom. In your case, you could for example try:

```
.child {
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  background-color: red;
}
```